Edit a specific part of image uploaded to ChatGPT (NOT an image generated)
If I click on an image generated by ChatGPT, I can edit part of it by selecting that area and describing with text the change wanted by clicking here:

But if I upload my own image, I don't see anyway to select an area of it only, so I can edit an area of it only.
